# How to call an object from the same class

Tags: java, object

I have a car racing program and I have a Car class which is responsible for one Car. It has a field called currentRace which stores the race the car is currently in. In my race class, in the constructor I am trying to create as many cars as the user wants to input,but how do I assign that race to the cars currentrace field.

```
/*
*/
public class Car
{
    private String name;
    //the amount of fuel currently in the car.
    //This is expressed as a whole number percentage, from 0% to 100%
    public int currentFuelLevel;
    //The number of seconds a car is slower per lap when it is raining
    private int rainSlowDown;
    //The total time take in a single race
    private int totalTime;
    //The race that the car is currently participating in
    private Race currentRace;
    private int damageLevel;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Car
     */
    public Car(String name, int rainSlowDown, int currentFuelLevel,int damageLevel)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.rainSlowDown = rainSlowDown;
       this.currentFuelLevel = currentFuelLevel;
       totalTime = 0;
       this.damageLevel = damageLevel;
    }

public void setCurrentRace(Race currentRace)
    {
        this.currentRace = currentRace;
    }
    

public class Race
{
    //the cars participating in the race

    /*
     * The number of seconds it takes for a car to complete a single lap
     * in this race, on average. Each race can have a different
     * averageLapTime, since races take place on different race tracks
     */
    private int averageLapTime;
    //this tracks information that can affect the time taken to complete
    //a single lap
    private boolean isRaining;
    private ArrayList<Car> cars;
    //private Race race1;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Race
     */
    public Race(int numberOfCars, int numberOfLaps,int averageLapTime, boolean isRaining)
    {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i< numberOfCars; i++){
            Random random = new Random();
            int rainSlowDown = random.nextInt(100);
            int currentFuelLevel = random.nextInt(100);
            int damageLevel = random.nextInt(100);
            Car cari = new Car(Integer.toString(i),rainSlowDown,currentFuelLevel,damageLevel);
            cars.add(cari);
            **cari.setCurrentRace(race1);**
        }
        this.numberOfLaps = numberOfLaps;
        this.averageLapTime = averageLapTime;
        this.isRaining = isRaining;
    }
```

The bit in bold is where I am trying to set the cars currentRace field to the race object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `this` instead of `race1`: `cari.setCurrentRace(this);`

Answer (score 2):

try to use `cari.setCurrentRace(this);`